# Batch malfunction

Tags: batch-file

This is a script my friend wrote for fun and there are two things that I can't figure out why it's not working. One question number 12 is always right no mater what the input. Also if you hit enter all the way through the questionnaire it automatically selects number 1 and I'm not sure why.

@echo off
    color 0c

```
title food quiz!

:begin
echo.
echo       Hello! and welcome to the ...FOOD QUIZ...
echo.
echo  To enter your answer, choose your answer, press space, then type the number 
echo your answer was listed as and press enter.
pause.
cls


set score=0
:Q1
echo.
echo question 1
echo.
echo    In which country did creme brulee originate?
echo.
echo 1. Italy
echo 2. Japan
echo 3. France
echo.
pause


set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A

if %x%==2 goto B

if %x%==3 goto C


:A
cls
echo.
echo Sorry!... creme brulee is a french dish.  
pause
goto Q2

:B
cls
echo.
echo Sorry!... creme brulee is a french dish.  
pause
goto Q2

:C
cls
echo.
echo Correct!
pause
set /a score=score+1
goto Q2


:Q2
cls
echo.
echo question 2
echo.
echo    A waz wan is a celebratory ___ course meal from the Kashmir valley of india.  
echo.
echo 1. 10
echo 2. 25
echo 3. 36
echo.
pause
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A1

if %x%==2 goto B1

if %x%==3 goto C1



:A1
cls
echo.
echo Sorry!... a waz wan is a 36 course meal.  only for special occasions.  
pause
cls
goto Q3

:B1
cls
echo.
echo Sorry!... a waz wan is a 36 course meal.  only for special occasions.  
pause
cls
goto Q3

:C1 
cls
echo.
echo Yes!  waz wans are only for special occasion.  
pause
cls
set /a score=score+1
goto Q3


:Q3
cls
echo.
echo question 3
echo.
echo    What is "chiqueti"? (pronounced chiketi)
echo.
echo 1. small gourmet snacks favored by the gondoleirs of venice.
echo 2. sausages from finland.
echo 3. small bite sized rolls served as streetfood in the phillipines.
echo.
pause
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A2

if %x%==2 goto B2

if %x%==3 goto C2

:A2
cls
echo.
echo Correct!
pause
cls
set /a score=score+1
goto Q4

:B2
cls
echo.
echo Nope! Chiqueti are small gourmet snacks favored by the gondoleirs of venice.
pause
cls
goto Q4

:C2
cls
echo.
echo Nope! Chiqueti are small gourmet snacks favored by the gondoleirs of venice.
pause
cls
goto Q4

:Q4
cls
echo.
echo question 4
echo.
echo    Haggis is the national dish of which Country in the united Kingdom?
echo.
echo 1. England
echo 2. Scotland
echo 3. Wales
pause
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A3

if %x%==2 goto B3

if %x%==3 goto C3

:A3
cls
echo.
echo Incorrect! haggis is the national dish of scotland.  haggis is the ground up 
echo pluck of a sheep, mixed with oats and   echo onions, then stuffed in a sheep stomach and steamed.  
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q5

:B3
echo.
echo Yep! haggis is the ground up pluck of a sheep, mixed with oats and onions, then stuffed in a sheep stomach and steamed.  
echo.
pause
cls
set /a score=score+1
goto Q5

:C3
cls
echo.
echo Incorrect! haggis is the national dish of scotland.  haggis is the ground up 
echo pluck of a sheep, mixed with oats and onions, then stuffed in a sheep stomach and steamed.  
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q5

:Q5
cls
echo.
echo question 5
echo.
echo    What is Borscht?
echo.
echo 1. an entree.
echo 2. a dessert.
echo 3. a soup like side dish.
echo.
pause
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A4

if %x%==2 goto B4

if %x%==3 goto c4

:A4
cls
echo.
echo Sorry! Borscht is a russian soup like side dish.
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q6

:B4
cls
echo.
echo Sorry! Borscht is a russian soup like side dish.
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q6

:C4
cls
echo.
echo Yes! Borscht is usually a liquidy vegetable puree, sometimes containing milk.  
echo.
pause
cls
set /a score=score+1
goto Q6

:Q6
echo.
echo question 6
echo. 
echo    Bleenies (aka bleens) are a popular streetfood of which country?
echo.
echo 1. Norway
echo 2. Russia
echo 3. romania
echo.
pause
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A5
if %x%==2 goto B5
if %x%==3 goto C5

:A5
echo.
echo Incorrect! Bleenies are a popular streetfood of Russia.
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q7

:B5 
echo.
echo Yes! 
echo.
pause
cls
set /a score=score+1
goto Q7

:C5 
echo.
echo Incorrect! Bleenies are a popular streetfood of Russia.
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q7



:Q7
echo.
echo question 7
echo.
echo    Kahlia is a Moraccan dish...What is "kahlia"? 
echo.
echo 1. Meat, preserved in its own fat.
echo 2. A type of lamb stew with dates.
echo 3. A tea containing cinnamon, reportedly an aphrodisiac.
echo.
pause 
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A6
if %x%==2 goto B6
if %x%==3 goto C6

:A6
echo.
echo Yes!  Kahlia can be cooked with eggs and served as a breakfast food.
echo.
pause
set /a score=score+1
cls
goto Q8

:B6
echo.
echo Sorry! Kahlia is meat preserved in fat.  
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q8

:C6
echo.
echo Sorry! Kahlia is meat preserved in fat.  
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q8


:Q8
echo.
echo question 8
echo.
echo    Muktuk is eaten by the native people of Alaska.  What is muktuk?
echo.
echo 1. Raw seal skin with a layer of blubber.
echo 2. Raw dolphin skin with a layer of blubber.
echo 3. Raw whale skin with a layer of blubber.
echo.
pause 
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A7
if %x%==2 goto B7
if %x%==3 goto c7

:A7
echo.
echo Sorry! Muktuk is Raw whale skin with a layer of blubber.
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q9

:B7
echo.
echo Sorry! Muktuk is Raw whale skin with a layer of blubber.
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q9

:C7
echo.
echo Yep!
echo.
pause
set /a score=score+1
cls
goto Q9


:Q9
echo.
echo question 9
echo.
echo Muktuk can be used to make which native Alaskan delicacy?
echo.
echo 1. Lunuk. 
echo 2. Tunuk. 
echo 3. Dunuk. 
echo.
pause 
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A8
if %x%==2 goto B8
if %x%==3 goto C8

:A8
echo.
echo Nope! Muktuk is used to make Dunuk. Dunuk is a fermented whale oil used as a sauce for other whale products.
echo.
pause 
cls
goto Q10

:B8
echo.
echo Nope! Muktuk is used to make Dunuk. Dunuk is a fermented whale oil used as a sauce for other whale products.
echo.
pause 
cls
goto Q10

:C8
echo.
echo Yes! Dunuk is a fermented whale oil used as a dipping sauce for other whale products.
pause
set /a score=score+1
cls
goto Q10

:Q10
echo.
echo question 10
echo.
echo    Kopi Luwak is which type of beverage?
echo.
echo 1. A Balinese broth made from rhino beetle larvae.
echo 2. A coffee made from digested coffe beans excreted from the wild civet cat.
echo 3. A cold smoothie like drink also made from muktuk.
echo.
pause 
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A9
if %x%==2 goto B9
if %x%==3 goto C9

:A9 
echo.
echo Incorrect!  Kopi Luwak is a coffee made from digested and excreted coffee beans ingested by the civet cat.  
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q11

:B9
echo.
echo Yes! Kopi Luwak is a coffee made from digested and excreted coffee beans ingested by the civet cat.  
echo.
pause
set /a score=score+1
cls
goto Q11

:C9
echo.
echo Incorrect!  Kopi Luwak is a coffee made from digested and excreted coffee beans ingested by the civet cat.  
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q11




:Q11
echo.
echo question 11
echo.
echo What is "Hicarl"?
echo.
echo 1. fermented meat from the greenlandic shark.  
echo 2. A Finish greeting used only to greet people named Carl.
echo 3. A native Maori pork dish.
echo.
pause
cls

if %x%==1 goto A10
if %x%==2 goto B10
if %x%==3 goto C10

:A10
echo.
echo Yes!
echo.
echo Hicarl is made in Iceland using the Greenlandic shark.  
echo.
pause
set /a score=score+1
cls
goto Q12

:B10
echo.
echo No!
echo.
echo Hicarl is made in Iceland using the Greenlandic shark.  
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q12


:C10
echo.
echo No!
echo.
echo Hicarl is made in Iceland using the Greenlandic shark.  
echo.
pause
cls
goto Q12




:Q12
echo.
echo question 12
echo.
echo Where is it beleived that coffee originated?
echo.
echo 1. Ethiopia
echo 2. Hawaii
echo 3. Colombia
echo.
pause
cls

if %x%==1 goto A11
if %x%==2 goto B11
if %x%==3 goto C11



:A11
echo.
echo YES!
echo.
echo It is said that an Ethiopian herder observed that his goats became very frisky after eating the bean of the coffee tree.
echo.
pause
cls
set /a score=score+1
goto end

:B11
echo.
echo WRONG :(
echo.
echo It is said that an Ethiopian herder observed that his goats became very frisky after eating the bean of the coffee tree.
echo.
pause
cls
goto end

:C11
echo.
echo WRONG :(
echo.
echo It is said that an Ethiopian herder observed that his goats became very frisky after eating the bean of the coffee tree.
echo.
pause
cls
goto end






:end
echo Congrats! you have finished the food quiz!
echo              -----------------
echo your score is     %score%
echo             -----------------
echo.
echo 1. Play again
echo 2. exit.
echo.
pause 
cls

set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto begin
if %x%==2 exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set /p x=number` will not set %x% if you just hit enter. It just leaves %x% as it is. To correct it add a `set x=0` before `set /p x=number`. Also you can easily implement some error-checking (answers other than "1", "2" and "3"

As an Example:

```
:Q2
echo Question and answers

set x=0
set /p x=number
if %x%==1 goto A2
if %x%==2 goto B2
if %x%==3 goto C2
echo "wrong input"
goto :Q1
```

Also you should overthink the usage of `cls` they seem to be on odd places ^^

By correcting your code, you will notice the reason for the behavior of Q12 yourself - there is missing something.

Comment: Thank you, I will add some off your suggestion and send the code back to my friend.

Answer (score 0):

It does not think you chose "1" look in this code:

```
:Q1

rem You need this:
cls

echo stuff
set /p x=
if %x% == ?? goto A1

rem And this:
goto Q1

:A1
```

That will stop it form going to A1.

And for Q12 you need the `set /p x=` it's not there. :)

Edit: And you can use `set /a score+=1` not `set /a score=score+1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend will be happy to get it working correctly.